# Action Script 3. Timer starts count when I'm in menu, but game not started

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, timer, count

I'm creating flash game and I get strange problem. Timer starts count when I'm in menu, but game not started. In menu I have button "Play", after It is clicked It add timer, but It shows how long program is running (start count from current time).

This is main function which starts

```
        public function MemoryGame()
        {
            startMemoryGame.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startPlay);
}
```

This is button to start game:

```
function startPlay(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    startMemoryGame();

}
```

And here Is my function where Timer and other objects added.

```
    function startMemoryGame():void
            {


            timer = new Timer(1000); //create a new timer that ticks every second.
            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, tick, false, 0, true); //listen for the timer tick
            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, resetTimer);
            txtTime = new TextField();



            var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
                format.font = "Verdana";
                format.color = "#E50041";
                format.size = 22;
            txtTime.border = true;
            txtTime.borderColor = 0xFFFFFF;
                //format.bold = true;  
            //txtTime.x = 250;
            txtTime.width/2;

            var stageCenter_x:Number = stage.stageWidth/2;
            var stageCenter_y:Number = stage.stageHeight/2;
            var textCenter_x:Number = txtTime.width/2;
            var textCenter_y:Number = txtTime.height/2;
            txtTime.x = stageCenter_x - textCenter_x;
            txtTime.y = 55;     
            txtTime.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
            txtTime.defaultTextFormat = format;
            message_txt.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
            message_txt.defaultTextFormat = format;

                //here Timer starts
                txtTime.text = showTimePassed(0);
            addChild(txtTime);
            tmpTime = timer.currentCount;
            timer.start();


                _cards = new Array();
                _totalMatches = 18;
                _currentMatches = 0;
                createCards();
            }

            private function tick(e:Event):void {
            txtTime.text = showTimePassed(timer.currentCount - tmpTime);                    


    }
    function showTimePassed(startTime:int):String {

      var leadingZeroMS:String = ""; //how many leading 0's to put in front of the miliseconds
      var leadingZeroS:String = ""; //how many leading 0's to put in front of the seconds
      var leadingZeroM:String = "";

      var time = getTimer() - startTime; //this gets the amount of miliseconds elapsed
      var miliseconds = (time % 1000); // modulus (%) gives you the remainder after dividing, 

      if (miliseconds < 10) { //if less than two digits, add a leading 0
        leadingZeroMS = "0";
      }

      var seconds = Math.floor((time / 1000) % 60); //this gets the amount of seconds

      if (seconds < 10) { //if seconds are less than two digits, add the leading zero
        leadingZeroS = "0";
      }

      var minutes = Math.floor((time / (60 * 1000) ) );
        if (minutes < 10) { //if seconds are less than two digits, add the leading zero
        leadingZeroM = "0";
      }
      //60 seconds times 1000 miliseocnds gets the minutes
      return leadingZeroM + minutes + ":" + leadingZeroS + seconds ;
}
```

What is strange that if I remove command `timer.start()` I have the same problem, after I click "startPlay" button It adds current timer (for example: 00:12) just timer is stopped.

I tried to use `timer.reset();`, but the same problem, so I don't have more ideas what's wrong. And I don't understand why It starts count time if I don't used any functions before. Could you help me, please? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In `showTimePassed` you have this line:

```
var time = getTimer() - startTime;
```

[`getTimer()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getTimer%28%29) gets the time passed in milliseconds since the program started (see doc)

`startTime` *should* be the time in ms when you started the game.

So instead if using the Timer in `startMemoryGame`, just store the value of `getTimer()` in a member variable, and pass that variable as the parameter to `showTimePassed`. Or change the code of `showTimePassed` to suit your needs.

Just changing this:

```
private function tick(e:Event):void {
    txtTime.text = showTimePassed(timer.currentCount - tmpTime);                    
}
```

to this:

```
private function tick(e:Event):void {
    txtTime.text = showTimePassed(tmpTime);                    
}
```

and this:
    tmpTime = timer.currentCount;

to this
    tmpTime = getTimer();

It should give you the correct time, if you're not using `tmpTime` anywhere else. Otherwise just declare another variable.

Explanation: `showTimePassed` just outputs the time passed since the program started, but it subtracts the parameter `startTime` from that time. Passing 0 will give you the time since starting the program. My proposed changes store the time since execution of the program in `tmpTime` when you start the game, and passes it to `showTimePassed`.

So you start the program. getTime() will give ~0

Five seconds later you press the start button. getTime() will be ~5000, stored in tmpTime

showTimePassed is called say 1 second later with tmpTime (5000). getTimer() gives 6000, subtract startTime gives you 1000 which is one second since you pressed start.

Here is some info on member variables by the way: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Member_variable

Comment: Thank you for answer. I really misunderstood what I need to do, If I delete getTimer() from showTimePassed It always show 0 and what you mean ` just store the value of getTimer() in a member variable`?

Comment: my point wasn't to remove getTimer, the function showTimePassed works but it is built on a different premise, namely that you pass it the time in ms *when you started playing*. So you need to store that time somewhere. Possibly in tmpTime or declare a new variable. I edited my answer to be clearer on this

Comment: Thank you for answer, that worked for me. I have question now how to return time when game over? I mean how to get current time when timer stops? Before I used this `urlVars.time = timer.currentCount;` but I don't know if this working yet correct.

Comment: how about storing `getTime() - tmpTime` at the game over event? I would only use the Timer class for the update event of the time-display. Although using the `timer.currentCount` should work too.

Just try out a few things, read the documentation of the function to understand what they do and work out a solution that suits your needs. This really isn't that difficult a task, especially now that you have the rest of the time display working correctly