# Action Script 3. How to set background

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, background, background-image

I'm creating flash game, here is restart button and I have function for delete all objects (children) from the stage.

```
function restartGame(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    while (numChildren > 0) {
        removeChildAt(0);
}
addChild(_cards);

//here I need to add background

    startMemoryGame();

}
```

At normal I don't need to add background, when game is started It is added automatic. In library It is called background.jpg, I converted It to graphic and now I named It just background added linkage "Background" but `addChild(background);` doesn't work for me.
Could you help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you just set linkage on the image, in that case go :

```
var background:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new Background);
addChild(background);
```

If it's a MovieClip symbol with linkage set, you can do this :

```
var background:Background = new Background;
addChild(background);
```

Comment: I got this error `1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Background to an unrelated type flash.display:BitmapData.` I imported 
 `import flash.display.BitmapData;` but the same. And I use `private var background:Background;`

Comment: What is your symbol in the library ? Is it a MovieClip ? Or is it just an image with linkage set ? How you instantiate it, depends on what you have it defined as in the library.

Comment: Thank you, second way is correct. Could you help me with this question too, please? Thank you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16447462/action-script-3-timer-starts-count-when-im-in-menu-but-game-not-started

Comment: Both ways are correct, just a matter of how you are setting things up in the library determines if it will work for you or not. You were not clear about what you were doing.